# Sphinx search for distinct values with counts

Tags: sphinx

I have an "objects" table (actually a result of a SQL join), with data like this:

```
ID, content, category_id
1, some searchable data, 5
2, some more data, 6
3, more data, 5
4, another example, 7
```

I'd like to use Sphinx to index this table and return *distinct* category_id values, as well as *how many* records had data hits, sorted by the number of hits.

For instance, if I search this index with the term "data", I'd like the result to be:

```
5, 2 hits
6, 1 hit
```

This would be pretty trivial with grouping and counts in MySQL, but I can't get my head around doing the same thing with a Sphinx search.

What should my sql_query be? How should I use the PHP API to get the results I need?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $cl->SetGroupBy( "category_id", SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR, "@count desc" );
```

*distinct category-ids* would be in `total_found`

*how many records had data hits* you don't directly get, the easiest way would be to run a non-group by query, then it is in `total_found`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'm trying to return the actual category IDs as my document IDs, as well as the count of objects *in each category*. I may be misunderstanding, but it looks like this answer may only return counts.

Comment: The category_id is found in the 'attrs' array, within each match. See also `setSelect`